# Move Created Templates to a Folder identically matching a value on index

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Code below saved files to a static location and renamed them based on an index 'File names' starting on position A1.

Instead of them being saved to a constant location, can I make it save to a subfolder matching another value on the 'File names' sheet? This would be under B1 on the 'File names' sheet with names like, "John", "Dave", "Kathy" etc.

I appreciate any help!

```
Public Sub SaveTemplate()
  Const strSavePath As String = "C:\My Documents\"
  Const strTemplatePath As String = "C:\My Documents\template.xls"

  Dim rngNames As Excel.Range
  Dim rng As Excel.Range
  Dim wkbTemplate As Excel.Workbook
  
  Set rngNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Names").Range("A1:A200").Values
  
  Set wkbTemplate = Application.Workbooks.Open(strTemplatePath)
  
  For Each rng In rngNames.Cells
    wkbTemplate.SaveAs strSavePath & rng.Value
  Next rng
  
  wkbTemplate.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: There's just one folder name in B1, or a folder name for each file name?

Comment: `wkbTemplate.SaveAs strSavePath & rng.offset(0,1).value & "\" & rng.Value`

Comment: Hey Tim, it would be multiple. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Then that line I posted should work if the subfolder is to the right of the filename

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Public Sub SaveTemplate()
    Const strSavePath As String = "C:\My Documents\"
    Const strTemplatePath As String = "C:\My Documents\template.xls"
    
    Dim rngNames As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rngNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Names").Range("A1:A200")
    
    With Application.Workbooks.Open(strTemplatePath)
        For Each rng In rngNames.Cells
            'include folder name from Col B
            .SaveAs strSavePath & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & "\" & rng.Value
        Next rng
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```